# Why can't i get an exit command to work

Tags: python-2.7

Hi i'm sorta new to python 2.7.3 and i'm trying to code an automatic exit clause after both of the if statements.

```
import os

password = "Anhur"
attempt = 0
while (password != "Anhur") and (attempt <= 3):
    password = raw_input("Password: ")
    attempt = attempt + 1
    if attempt == 3:
        print ("You have used all your attempts, the system will now close..")
        print (" The shifting sands have ended you.")
        break

if (password == "Anhur"):
    print ("You conquered the sands")

os.exit(1)
```

This is what i've got but it never seems to work i've tries sys.exit(0) as well. any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `exit()`

---

```
import os

password=""
attempt=0
while (password != "Anhur") and (attempt<3):
    password=raw_input("Password: ")
    attempt+=1

    if (password == "Anhur"):
        print ("You conquered the sands")
        exit()

print ('''You have used all your attempts, the system will now close..")
The shifting sands have ended you.''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi [rsm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3672754/rsm),
useful answer. However initial code is buggy and IMHO useless. Please try this one:

```
import os

password = ""
attempts = 0
found = False
while (attempts <= 2):
    password = raw_input("Password: ")
    attempts = attempts + 1
    if (password == "Anhur") :
        found = True
        break

if found:
    print ("You conquered the sands")
    exit(0)
else:
    print ("You have used all of your attempts, the system will now close..")
    print (" The shifting sands have ended you.")
    exit(1)
```

This allows to discriminate correctly at OS level the success/failure, e.g. in the variable status in csh/tcsh (my default shell at work) or in other ways in more useful/modern shells.